# How to add a class to a checkbox in a form?

Tags: forms

I would like to add the class 'checkradios' to checkboxes in an entity form, is it possible do this in the theme layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can copy `theme_checkbox()` from `includes/form.inc`:

```
function theme_checkbox($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element['#checked'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

into your theme's `template.php` file and rename it accordingly:

```
function YOURTHEME_checkbox($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element['#checked'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox', 'checkradios')); // <-- checkradios added in here

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

along with the addition of the `checkradios` class and this will be added to each checkbox.

Now, if you want to restrict it to certain fields, you can look inside `$element` and add some additional logic to this.